# Counting daily visitors in a log file

Tags: ruby, bash, perl, logging, sed

I have a log file of visitors which spans over 1.5 years. Every line represents a page load. Structure of each line is the following:

```
2016-08-05 00:48:10 +0200 -> 170.67.51.153   -> Beijing - Beijing Shi: China -> http://example.com/?ref=1676 -> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html) -> AS55966 Beijing Baidu Netcom Science and Technology Co., Ltd. -> Beijing Baidu Netcom Science and Technology Co. -> 0.9301
```

I used " -> " to delimit fields.

My Log file is about 50MB in size, and it takes a long time to parse the whole file for today's or yesterday's visitor count, because those actual lines are of course at the end of the file.

I would like to use the bash command "tac" which is a reverse "cat" or something similar technique to get the lines in a reverse order. My first attempt was (to get daily visitors of for example 2016-08-04):

```
tac visitor_log.txt|grep 2016-08-04|cut -d " " -f 5|sort|uniq|wc -l
```

It of course outputs the visitor count, but unfortunately it is also time consuming as it reads through the whole file, because one can't tell "grep" to stop matching the lines if the previous line matched and the actual line doesn't match.

Maybe should I emulate "tac" in Ruby to get the daily visitor count effectively? Or should I using some flip-flop technique which is possibly available in "sed"? Unfortunately I don't know "sed" at all.

Comment: 50MB is a tiny file, and it should take a fraction of a second to process it. Do you mean 50GB? Perl is best suited for processing text files.

Comment: You say *"I used " -> " to delimit fields"*, but what is the real delimiter? It's never a good idea to alter your live data when you post a question. What is `cut -d " " -f 5` supposed to produce? From your data it would be the second `->`, but I imagine you mean the first `Beijing`?

Comment: Not sure why but I feel inclined to ask. Why are you not using a service for this? Google Analytics is extremely easy to implement and has a ruby app client. It would be far faster and more informative than parsing a text file. Otherwise load this into a database as it will again perform far better than text parsing.

Comment: Yes, I used " -> " for delimiting fields, but "cut" command can cut input only by one character, so I used " " space to split the lines, and the 5th split is exactly the IP address.

Comment: File is only 50 MB now, but as the traffic builds up and time goes by it can grow huge.

Comment: Thx for offering Google Analytics, I have never heard of it till now.  I think in this case I can't use it, because I developed a few other services now which are based on this log file, for example filtering out robots, showing new visitors real time, showing the latest date of visit of recurring visitors real time, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to know how to help without more information, but this Perl program will display the number of visits for every day logged

The program expects the input file as a parameter on the command line. The output is as simplistic as the sample data you have given, and shows a single visit on 5 August 2016

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %visits;

while ( <> ) {
    next unless /^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)/;
    ++$visits{$1};
}

for my $date ( sort keys %visits ) {
    printf "%s  --  %d\n", $date, $visits{$date};
}
```

#### output

```
2016-08-05  --  1
```

It should take only a second or two if your file is really only 50MB

I have tested by replicating the line you show to create a 50MB file, and it is processed in less than half a second, reporting 162,823 visits on one day

I suggest that you reformat your log file into a database so that you can query it more easily. That way you will have to process the log file just once; thereafter your queries will be instantaneous